# How to do the reverse of bcf merge?

Tags: bcftools

How can one do the reverse of bcftools merge?
To get one sample back out of the merged one.
Without holding reference sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bcftools` has the `view` command which can do this. Create a text file (`samples`) which has the names of the samples you want, one per line, and then:

```
bcftools view -S samples merged.vcf.gz > new.vcf
```

Or, if you're running a shell that supports it, you can use input redirection for a single sample name:

```
bcftools view -S <(echo "sample name") merged.vcf.gz > new.vcf
```